# Not receiving broadcast UDP messages when binding to specific address

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, udp

I send datagrams using this socket:

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, port);
```

(then use the SendTo method)

To listen at the other end, I use this socket:

```
this.udpListenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
this.udpListenSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
EndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
this.udpListenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
```

and this works as expected. It seemed a little crude to me though and I was wondering whether this could cause me to get the same datagram multiple times, once from each of the machine's IP addresses (which does not seem to be the case but this is not the point). So I tried to bind to a specific address, like the one provided by the DHCP server.

This however does not work, I get nothing. I only get something from the listening socket when binding to IPAddress.Any.

Why? Do I need to specify extra socket options? Am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind socket to specific ip address which is not `IPAddress.Any` (0.0.0.0, special one) - you will only receive packets with destination ip set to this address. The broadcast packet you send has destination address `IPAddress.Broadcast` (255.255.255.255), it does not match the ip you bound your socket to. So even though this packet actually arrives to the target interface, and in theory you could receive it - it will be dropped because of destination mismatch.

For this reason the most common approach to receive UDP broadcast packages is to bind to 0.0.0.0. However, if sender does not use limited broadcast address (255.255.255.255) but instead uses broadcast address of specific subnet - then you can receive it on the same broadcast address of specific subnet.

For example, I have local IP 192.168.0.105, and broadcast address of this subnet is 192.168.0.255. If you change your sender code to broadcast to this address, and change your receiver code to bind to this address (and not to ip address of your interface, so NOT to 192.168.0.105 in my example) - then you will receive the broadcast the way you wanted.

Comment: I see. So in order to receive a sent datagram, the local endpoint specified by the receiver must either be 0.0.0.0 ("catch all") or exactly match the remote endpoint specified by the sender. To me the idea that the receiver must be aware of the exact subnet specification of the sender is counter intuitive to the concept of broadcasting. I guess it is still useful to be able to cancel out noise outside of your subnet.

Comment: But sender and receiver are in the same subnet?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same subnet. I see the described behavior also on the local machine.

Comment: I refer to "receiver must be aware of the exact subnet specification of the sender". Since they are in the same subnet receiver must be aware of its own subnet specification only.

Comment: You mean if the receiver is in a C-type subnet, it could assume the sender broadcast to x.x.x.255 (with x.x.x being the first three octets of the receiver's address)?

Comment: Yes, I'd even say it's often better to send to actual subnet broadcast address instead of 255.255.255.255. That address is called "limited broadcast address" for a reason. Also if you are connected to multiple networks, 255.255.255.255 will only broadcast in one of them, so in this case you'll have to be specific anyway.